# babel-loader: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Deleting local variable in strict mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, strict-mode

I'm using `babel-loader` in `webpack` with a custom babel-plugin to transform some thirdparty code into a format that passes through Webpack's bundler without trouble. However, when my code runs through babel's parser (babylon) to build the AST, I get the following error:

`Module build failed: SyntaxError: Deleting local variable in strict mode`

I found the line in bablyon that triggers this message: https://github.com/babel/babylon/blob/master/src/parser/expression.js#L236

Looking at that code, it seems like I should be able to disable strict mode parsing in babylon by setting `this.state.strict` to `false`. The problem is I don't know how to set `this.state.strict` from `babel-loader`. I'm hoping someone else knows more about this.

Here are some things I've tried so far:

1. `strict: false` and `strictMode: false` in `query`

   ```
   {
       test: /\.js$/,
       include: /bower_components/, //only thirdparty
       loader: 'babel',
       query: {
           strict: false,
           plugins: [__dirname + '/babel-plugins/custom-plugin']
       }
   }
   ```
2. `strict: false` and `strictMode: false` with plugin

   ```
   {
       test: /\.js$/,
       include: /bower_components/, //only thirdparty
       loader: 'babel',
       query: {
           plugins: [
               [__dirname + '/babel-plugins/custom-plugin', {strict: false}]
           ]
       }
   }
   ```
3. Set `state.opts.strict` to false in `Program` within `custom-plugin.js` (but this shouldn't work because babylon parses the code and fails before passing the AST off for traversal)

   ```
   module.exports = function (params) {
       return {
           visitor: {
               Program: function (path, state) {
                   state.opts.strict = false;
               }
           }
       };
   };
   ```
4. Use `blacklist` in `webpack.config.js` and `.babelrc` (which was removed in babel v6 so this shouldn't work anyway)

   ```
   {
       test: /\.js$/,
       include: /bower_components/, //only thirdparty
       loader: 'babel',
       query: {
           plugins: [__dirname + '/babel-plugins/custom-plugin']
       }
   }
   ```

I can think of some hacky solutions to this problem, but this flag should be accessible at the surface through `babel-loader` or `.babelrc` in some form or another.

Comment: maybe you should look at fixing the cause of the error, rather than a way around it

Comment: or tried `strict:false` at the first level of that object (i.e. same level as test:, loader:,  include: etc)

Comment: Fixing the cause of the error would mean modifying the source of a thirdparty library, which is not what I'm trying to do. I suppose I could submit a pull request with the changes that make this work then pull in the newest version of the library if the pull request gets approved, but I think removing the `delete someIdentifier;` statements would change the desired behavior of the library without a significant overhaul.

Comment: `strict: false` adjacent to `test`, `include`, `loader`, and `query` doesn't work because `babel-loader` doesn't pass any of those properties to babel or my custom babel plugin.

Comment: Removal of `delete identifier` would not alter the behavior since using delete on an unqualified identifier does nothing and returns false, or throws an error in strict mode. Delete works with object properties not with variables. To be fair that's a problem with the 3rd party module that you could revoke yourself or should ask the author to do so. You could also try using some old version without this code if one's available.

Comment: Also note that ES modules and classes are in strict mode by default.

Comment: The package you are using is in archive mode. Maybe going to the new package will eliminate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your presets. This could help.

```
presets: [
'es2015'
]
```

to be

```
presets: [
['es2015', {modules: false}]
]
```

Comment: Your response would be improved by an explanation.