# Using epson SDK in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, lib, epson

I want to use the EPSON JavaScript SDK in my vue (2.6.14) app. I tried to import die epson js file like this:

```
import epson from '../../public/epos-2.18.0'
```

Importing the script will result in a parsing error

```
4:103598  error  Parsing error: Deleting local variable in strict mode.
```

I found something similar here: [babel-loader: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Deleting local variable in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987089/babel-loader-module-build-failed-syntaxerror-deleting-local-variable-in-stric), but that did not help me at all.

Is there any common approach to import library's like that?

Comment: It's unlikely it's a module, so it may make no sense to import it as `epson`. See newer posts in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821312/how-to-remove-global-use-strict-added-by-babel , as older ones apply to old Babel versions . You can always put it to public and load as any other third-party script.

Comment: With "load as any other thrid-party script" do you mean that i load it inside my index.html with a <scrtip> tag?

Comment: Either that, or add script tag dynamically, e.g. with vue-plugin-load-script

Comment: I've tried this first, if I do that, and use epson like `var ePosDev = new epson.ePOSDevice();` it will tell me that epson is not defined.

Comment: Either a script didn't load, or something else happened.

Comment: I loaded the script sucessfully with `Vue.loadScript("http://localhost:8001/epos-2.18.0.js")
.then(() => {
  var ePosDev = new epson.ePOSDevice();
  console.log(ePosDev)
})
.catch(() => {
});`

The log shows me the loaded ePOSDevice. But anyways.. I still getting this error: `Failed to compile.

./main.js
Module Error (from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

/path/to/project/src/main.js
  60:21  error  'epson' is not defined  no-undef

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)`

Comment: It's linter error, not a real one. You can disable no-undef rule, or use window.epson

Comment: Now it seems to work for me, you helped me a lot! Thank you!